# Adding a table to ggplot with gridExtra and annotation_custom() changes y-axis limits

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I tried adding a little summary table to a plot which I created with `ggplot2::ggplot()`. The table is added via `gridExtra::tableGrob()` to the saved ggplot object.

My problem is that this seems to change the y-limits of my original plot.
Is there a way to avoid that without having to specify the limits again via `ylim()`?

Here is a minimal example for the problem using the ChickWeight dataset:

```
# load packages
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

# create plot
plot1 = ggplot(data = ChickWeight, aes(x = Time, y = weight, color = Diet)) +
        stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_boot", size = 1, alpha = .5) 
plot1
# create table to add to the plot
sum_table = aggregate(ChickWeight$weight, 
                      by=list(ChickWeight$Diet), 
                      FUN = mean)
names(sum_table) = c('Diet', 'Mean')
sum_table = tableGrob(sum_table)

# insert table into plot
plot1 + annotation_custom(sum_table)
```

[image: ylim problem with annotation_custom()]

**EDIT:**
I just figured out that it seems to be an issue with `stat_summary()`. When I use another geom/layer, then the limits stay as they were in the original plot. Another example for that:

```
plot2 = ggplot(data = ChickWeight, aes(x = Time, y = weight, color = Diet)) +
        geom_jitter() 
plot2
plot2 + annotation_custom(sum_table)
```

[image: ylim problem with annotation_custom()]

Comment: I am not sure of the problem, but I don't think it is an issue with `stat_summary` it you do `plot2+stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_boot", size = 1, alpha = .5)+annotation_custom(sum_table)` then your ylim is preserved.

Comment: That's interesting. It sets the y-limits for the whole data range instead of that from `geom = 'pointrange'` (which `stat_summary` uses by default). So if I see that correctly, in my first example ylim gets adjusted to the range of the summarized and displayed values (from `pointrange`), but when adding `annotation_custom` it uses the range of the whole data again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The y-range for plot1 is different from plot2, the reason being that `annotation_custom` takes its aesthetics from the original `aes` statement, not the modified data frame used by `stat_summary()`. To get the y-ranges for the two plots to be the same (or roughly the same - see below), stop `annotation_custom` getting its aesthetics from the original data. That is, move `aes()` inside the `stat_summary()`.

```
# load packages
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

# create plot
plot1 = ggplot(data = ChickWeight) +
        stat_summary(aes(x = Time, y = weight, color = Diet), fun.data = "mean_cl_boot", size = 1, alpha = .5) 
plot1

# create table to add to the plot
sum_table = aggregate(ChickWeight$weight, 
                      by=list(ChickWeight$Diet), 
                      FUN = mean)
names(sum_table) = c('Diet', 'Mean')
sum_table = tableGrob(sum_table)

# insert table into plot
plot2 = plot1 + annotation_custom(sum_table, xmin = 10, xmax = 10, ymin = 200, ymax = 200) 
plot2
```

[image]

By the way, the reason the two plots will not give the exact same y-range is because of the bootstrap function in `stat_summary()`. Indeed, plot p1 repeatedly, and you might notice slight changes in the y-range. Or check the y-ranges in the build data.

**Edit** Updating to ggplot2 ver 3.0.0

```
ggplot_build(plot1)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.range
ggplot_build(plot2)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.range
```

Recall that ggplot does not evaluate functions until drawing time - each time p1 or p2 is drawn, a new bootstrap sample is selected.